# Dart enum compiler error

Tags: enums, compiler-errors, dart

I am trying to define the following "enum" in Dart:

```
class Place {
    static const SigninPlace = const Place._("", new Map<String,String> { "fizz": "buzz"});
    static const SignoutPlace = const Place._("", null);

    static get values => [SigninPlace, SignoutPlace];

    final String name;
    final Map<String,String> params;

    const Place._(this.name, this.params);
}
```

But am getting a compiler error on the `SigninPlace` declaration:

> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

**Why, and what can I do to fix this?** (Hint: each `Place`'s map of `<String,String>` won't change and is known at startup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define *const* all its member have to be constant expression. In your case `new Map<String,String> { "fizz": "buzz"}` is not a constant expression. You have to used `const <String,String>{ "fizz": "buzz"}` to create a constant *Map*.

```dart
class Place {
  static const SigninPlace = const Place._("", 
      const <String,String>{ "fizz": "buzz"});
  static const SignoutPlace = const Place._("", null);

  static get values => [SigninPlace, SignoutPlace];

  final String name;
  final Map<String,String> params;

  const Place._(this.name, this.params);
}
```